# How to to automatically refuse GDPR consent requests?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, gdpr

How to to automatically refuse GDPR consent requests and only opt-in strictly necessary cookies (session cookies, etc...) ?

I tried the **Never-Consent** WebExtension on both Firefox and Chromium but it does not work on youtube, google, dailymotion, *.stackexchange.com, etc...

How can this be set from within the browser's settings on modern browsers?

Comment: I've wondered this myself, but because each site implements these switches differently it's unlikely that one specific setting or option will be available inside the browser that will offer this function.

Comment: the https://consentomatic.au.dk/ add-on is available for popular browsers, but you might get better answers from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

All the sites I have used (many) have all different approaches for selecting all cookies, including a few "all or nothing".

There is no commonality and accordingly no practical way to automate this.

We all just have to accept (or not) as we go.

I have not seen any major issue in cookies from reasonable sites.

You might look at the cookie view apps and delete old cookies.  Nirsoft can do this, for example.

[Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html)